# How come this code generates crazy output in Node.js with learnyounode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn Node.js with 'Learnyounode' in Terminal on OSX. When I run the code below with **'learnyounode run programfile.js programfile.js'** I get the crazy output as shown in the image, and I don't understand why :) Is this the error that is thrown, or some easter egg in learnyounode?

The program below finds the number of newlines in a file that's input as argument when running the program with **$> learnyounode run programfile.js programfile.js**

```
var fs = require('fs') // adds fs module
var src = process.argv[2] 
var data

fs.readFile(src, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(data)
    var lines = data.split('\n').length - 1
    console.log(lines)
})
```

If you don't now about learnyounode, [see #learnyounode on nodeschool.io](http://nodeschool.io/#learn-you-node)

[image: crazy node.js output as PNG on Dropbox]

Thanks for enlighting me.

Comment: I see crazy output: A stacktrace error, and some oddball text. I assume you mean the former? Can you copy and paste the stacktrace into the question?

Comment: Also, looking at the stacktrace, it is showing a missing `,` after `fs.readFile(src` (should be `fs.readFile(src, 'utf8' ...`) which you appear to have edited into the code in your question. The stacktrace is referring to that `,`.

Comment: you are printing the data with `console.log(data)`, if you removed that line you wouldnt see all the text.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I mean the oddball text. I fixed the stacktrace error. I'm just curoius as to where the oddball text is coming from. 

Also thnks for pointing out the missing ,

Comment: @Sgnl the large amount of text was autogenerated every time I ran the program and got an error. It was not present in any files I loaded.

Comment: if you console.log(process.argv) you'll see a tmp directory where node is pulling the text from.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the screenshot and the code you pasted in differ. There is a comma missing in the screenshot.

Code both here and in the screenshot on the right hand side:

```
fs.readFile(src, 'utf8', function(err, data){
```

Screenshot on the left hand side:

```
fs.readFile(src 'utf8', function(err, data){
               ^ missing comma
```

So the screenshot version is letting you know that it sees an unexpected string `'utf'` because there isn't a comma after `src`.

Were you executing a version of the file that had the error by mistake?

Comment: As I'm new to Node i was wondering where the text came from, like 
'As busy as a damper piece of piss gutful of troppo. As cross as a slaps with as cross as a esky. It'll be brizzie to grab us a mate's rate. Gutful of cab sav no dramas watch out for the ...'

Thanks for pointing out the missing , - I already fixed that and then this massive text got output.

Comment: What exact command did you type when you ran the code? The `process.argv[2]` should be pulling in whatever follows `programname.js` in `node programname.js third_argument`.

Comment: learnyounode run myfirstasyncio.js myfirstasyncio.js

I just pulled in the same file as the program to avoid having a testfile for counting linebreaks.